# How to find in a directory 2 files with same name but different extension and put them in a new directory

Tags: bash

I have one problem with bash, I have in a directory some different files, for each files there is a copy in the same name but different extension, like that:

The file scripting is in the home directory and the directory with the files in home

```
~home/file_directory:
```

And the files are like this:

```
    pippo.cvs
    pippo.xlsx
    mimmo.cvs
    mimmo.xlsx
    lollo.cvs
    lollo.xlsx
```

I would like to have a new directory with the same name of the two file with them inside:

```
    pippo
    mimmo
    lollo

~home/file_directory/pippo:
    pippo.xlsx
    pippo.csv
```

so

```
pippo -> pippo.xlsx pippo.cvs
mimmo -> mimmo.xlsx mimmo.cvs
lollo -> lollo.xlsx lollo.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

First go into the directory where all the files are present

```
Administrators-MacBook-Pro:test anudeep$ for i in *;do mkdir ${i%.*};done
mkdir: lollo: File exists
mkdir: mimmo: File exists
mkdir: pippo: File exists
Administrators-MacBook-Pro:test anudeep$
```

The above creates directories with the filenames(without extension) ignore the "file exists" as the directory has already been created.

Then move the files to desired directories

```
Administrators-MacBook-Pro:test anudeep$ for i in *.*;do mv $i ${i%.*};done
```

You are done now!

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly basic scripting issue, the trick bit is extracting the directory name:

```
for fname in *.cvs *.xlsx
do
    # delete the shortest string on the right
    # starting with '.'
    dname=${fname%.*}

    # If the directory does not exist then create it
    [[ -d $dname ]] || mkdir "$dname"

    mv "$fname" "$dname"
done
```

Lots of "double quotes", just in case there are embedded spaces in the file names.